# My UICollectionView doesn't get populated with any cells when VoiceOver is on

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, accessibility, voiceover

I'm hitting a peculiar problem with accessibility in iOS 13.

I have a calendar that's implemented as a UICollectionView. If VoiceOver is turned on, the collection view is empty - it simply doesn't get populated with any UICollectionViewCells.

I've overridden the correct UICollectionViewDataSource calls. `numberOfSections` and `collectionView(numberOfItemsInSection)` are called, and returns correct nonzero values. But `collectionView(cellForItemAt)` is never called. That's what doesn't make any sense to me; it knows how many sections and how many items I have, but it doesn't care to ask about the items.

If I turn off VoiceOver, then it'll call `collectionView(cellForItemAt)` and it populates my collection view properly. And in iOS 12, everything works fine whether or not VoiceOver is on.

What am I missing, or how can I debug this? How could the state of VoiceOver affect whether my collection view gets populated?

Comment: show your code, this isn't a known issue so it must be in your implementation. we can't debug an issue with your code without seeing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We reported the problem to our Apple representative and got a response. What's happening is that in iOS 13, VoiceOver asks the collection view for information about a larger rect than is visible; this was an intentional change to support certain types of collection views whose content size is not known up-front. So it was calling our override of `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect:)` with a large negative Y values for the rect, and we didn't have any elements out there.

Our fix was to ignore the Y value of the rect we were given, and instead use a Y value of `0`. iOS was then able to find our collection view cells.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, however Brian's answer didn't work for me. Instead I found it was setting the delegate and datasource of the UICollectionView to nil that caused the issue. Removing the lines that set it to nil fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue (UICollectionView fine normally, but blank with VoiceOver on) and couldn't find the answer anywhere (none of the posted responses where the issue I was hitting).

My problem turned out to be for a vertical UICollectionView you can set the contentSize to `(width:0, height:something)` and it works perfectly. But with VoiceOver on it really doesn't like that `width:0` and doesn't attempt to load anything. The fix is just to set width to any value, even `width:1`, and suddenly it will start working again.

Issue on iOS 14.2 (didn't test other iOS versions)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, however the previously posted solutions of normalizing the rect passed into `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)` was not working (in fact, we were not even using the passed-in rect value at all -- the method signature in our implementation was `layoutAttributesForElements(in _: CGRect)`), nor was setting the contentSize on the collectionView directly as Kyle suggested.

What fixed the issue for me was overriding the `collectionViewContentSize` computed property on the `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass. Apparently, this method is configured by default to return `.zero`, which breaks the layout when voiceover is enabled. Still working on figuring out why this happens, but in the meantime adding the following to the  the following to the `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass fixed the issue:

```
override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
  guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return .zero }
  return collectionView.frame.size
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like apple sets the origin used for *layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)* to negative device height for some reason. I solved this by using this normalisation code.

```
func normalizeRect(_ rect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    guard rect.origin.x < 0, rect.origin.y < 0 else { return rect }
    let normalizedSize = CGSize(width: rect.origin.x + rect.width, height: rect.origin.y + rect.height)
    let value = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: normalizedSize)
    return value
}


Example iPhone 12max:
  * expected rect (0.0, 0.0, 428.0, 926.0)
  * given rect (-926.0, -926.0, 1354.0, 2778.0)
  * normalized rect: (0, 0, 428 (-926 + 1354), 1852 (-926 + 2278 == 2 * 926))
```